# How do you interpret the negative solution?

Tags: proof-explanation, quadratics, problem-solving

A rectangle is such that its area is $308 \,m^2$.

Its length is $8\, m$ longer than its width.

What is its length?

Let $x$ denote its width. Its length is then $x+8$ and $x$ satisfies

\begin{align}
x(x+8)&=308\\
x^2+8x-308&=0\\
(x+22)(x-14)&=0\\
x=-22 \quad \text{or} \quad x&=14.
\end{align}

*We select the positive value of $x$*, the width is $14\, m$, we have $14+8=22$, the length is $22\,m$.

> Question. *How do you interpret $x=-22$?*

Comment: If $x$ is its width it should be $x > 0$ by assumption.

Comment: How one would interpret $-22$ here?

Comment: "How do you interpret $x=-22$", um, you don't. It's about the side lengths of a rectangle. You see it's negative, discard the solution and never think about it again :)

Comment: @vrugtehagel funny:))!

Comment: @OlivierOloa Since $x > 0$, $-22$ cannot be a solution. There is nothing to interpret geometrically.

Comment: @Gibbs I know that... "There is nothing to interpret geometrically", what about another interpretation?

Comment: Maybe think about $R^2$ and first side is vector $(a,0)$ and other side is $(0,b)$ then the area is oriented. So we get 2 solutions $(14, 0), (0,22)$ and $(-22,0), (0,-14)$ (and other two solutions swaping vectors).

Comment: @OlivierOloa What about orientation? If you think $x \in \mathbb{R}$, i.e. the oriented real line, then $x=-22$ identifies the interval $[-22,0]$. Likewise, $x+8$ gives $[-14,0]$, so you get a specular rectangle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following problem:
Find the rectangle with corners $(0,0),(x,0),(x,y),(y,0)$ such that its area is $308$ and $x=y+8$.

This leads to the equation

$$308=|x||y|=|xy|=|y(y+8)|.$$
Resolving the absolute value we get two equations
$$y^2+8y-308=0,\quad y^2+8y+308 = 0.$$
The second one has no  real root, so you are left with exactly the equation you encountered in your solution only that in this case the negative values for $x,y$ also make sense.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. (+1) When you write "...the negative values for $x,y$ also make sense.", both $x,y$ can't be negative.

Comment: Oh, but they do. The two possible solution pairs are $(22,14)$ and $(-14,-22)$.

Comment: Oh, I think I've understood your point of view. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If we reformulate the question that you are asking in terms of integrals (since integrals and area are related) we could say that we are looking for the solution of

$$\int^{x+8}_0 x\,dt = 308 $$
There are indeed two solution, one which is $x=-22$. We have $x$ is negative and $x+8$ is negative, which means that it might be convenient to write
$$\int^{x+8}_0 x\,dt = \int^0_{x+8} - x \,dt$$
which we can interpret easily. We have that it is the rectangle on the left side of the vertical axis which also has the same area.

Comment: Thank you for your answer (+1).